# How to detect if a text on path is touched

Tags: android, text, path, android-custom-view

Does anyone has a hint for my intention.

I have a text with a specific size X on a path in my custom view ( android ). How can I detect if the area of the text is touched ? ( blue area )

[image]

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt API for that. Use an OnTouchListener, you get the X/Y coords and you have to figure it out yourself.